# How to change the name displayed in reverse dns lookup for exchange 2011

Tags: reverse-dns, windows-sbs-2011

When I run this command `ping -a <some-ip>` I get this result:

> Pinging x.y.com [ip-address] with 32 bytes of data:

The IP address points to **my** SBS 2011 Standard. Where can I change the name `x.y.com`?

I want to change the `x`.

Comment: Ask your provider.

Comment: @Sven I changed my provider and the name remains the same. This doesn't look to me like the new provider has set it. **AND** the SBS is running under the IP address of another company **BUT** `x.y.com` belongs to me so the provider doesn't have a clue what to set. I believe it is the _hostname_ of the SBS or something similar. I want to change only the `x` in the name.

Comment: Reverse names need to be set by the owner of the netblock.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're asking, but if you're asking where to configure the FQDN that Exchange Server uses in HELO/EHLO then that is configured in Exchange. If you're asking who manages the PTR record for the ip address that Exchange is using for outbound email then that is managed by the netblock "owner".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse record in DNS is generally controlled by your ISP, who may also be your datacenter/server provider.

As a small amount of background, the reverse records are the IP reversed under .in-addr.apra (for example 1.2.3.4 would be 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa) These are then delegated to whatever ISP or provider controls that address.

You will need to contact whomever provides you that IP, and ask about setting the reverse DNS for it. Most providers require that the forward dns already match (they require that 1.2.3.4 already resolve to some.site.example, before they will make the DNS change)

You can also query the SOA and NS records for that domain, to get an idea of whom to contact.

Comment: Thank you. I know what happened: My hoster didn't inform me he told the ISP to update the record and due to lack of skill in this subject I was confused. Furthermore - a _professional_ told me this is a SBS setting and because of this I asked this question. +1

Comment: The ISP has already changed the entry.